# Issue with clone mediator inside iterate in WSO2 ESBB 4.9.0

Tags: wso2-esb

I am implementing a scheduled task in WSO2 ESB 4.9.0. Implementation is as below.

1) Created a java mediator to fetch data from the data base and set the data in context
2) The above mediator is called from sequence, in the same sequence when mediator returns data to sequence, I need to call back end service for which I used clone mediator
3) So for each record in the contex, I run through iterate mediator and call mediator inside the clone will call back end service

4) we noticed call mediator inside clone is working in parallel and not sequential, though we change iterate mediator sequential mediation property to false..

We don't want to make it parallel as it impacts other business logic.

Is there anything I am missing here

Answer (score 0):

Use the [call mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Call+Mediator) with blocking mode to achieve sequential order within the iterator.